# Game with one male warrior and remaining PCs as village girls

Tags: product-identification

I remember coming across an article about this game where one player (who must be female if there is a female player at the table, according to the rules) plays a male wandering warrior, and everyone else plays a girl from the village and has to convince him, by one means or another, to stay and defend the village from oncoming doom. The concept of the game is really intriguing to me and I'd like to try and get a hold of it, but I can't remember the name of it for the life of me.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### [Kagematsu](https://sites.google.com/site/creamaliengames/Home/kagematsu-the-rpg)

> “It is Japan 1572, the end of the Seguko period of history. Like many transitions of power the country is filled with strife, warring factions pulling any able bodied men into war, leaving villages populated by only women, children and old men. Now a small, nearly indefensible village is living under the horror of a dangerous threat that casts its long shadow over the village. Without a defender, its people are almost certainly doomed.
>
> Enter Kagematsu, a wayward ronin fleeing a troubled past. Here is a defender for the village, if only he can be swayed from his meandering course. So it is that several young women conspire among themselves to win his affections and steer him to their cause...”
>
> Kagematsu is a fast paced story game for 3-6 players with quick scenes that should play out in one session. The game includes the 40 page game book with an expanded appendix and a gorgeous tri-fold Kagematsu screen.